# Submitting form which has onSubmit="return func();" using python 3.x

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

My second day on python, trying to learn webscraping.

I have a form in a webpage I'm trying to scrap data from

```
<form name="search" method="POST" action="index.php" onSubmit="return Search();">
```

The url automatically helps fill in the parameters for search but since the form uses `onSubmit()`, I can't figure out how to submit it using python. Previously I was just using `urllib.request` to get everything done.

Comment: Can you share the link? Most likely requests can do what you want

Comment: http://edulix.com/unisearch/index.php?&ap=0&pr=1&ma=5&te=0&ye=0

Answer (score 0):

To execute the javascript contained in your web page, you will need to use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). This will allow you to emulate the entire browser and submit forms such as this that depend on javascript. Another alternative is [Spynner](https://code.google.com/archive/p/spynner/).

The other option is to either look at the javascript source of `Search()` (or monitor any POSTs by the browser when you submit the form manually) to determine what data are posted to where by the javascript. You could then maybe emulate the same request with python.

Comment: nothing else other than selenium? I mean, I was hoping to bypass the process using python alone or atmost somehow parsing html/js through python, but then again I'm new to python.

Comment: @plungehead It really depends on how javascript-heavy the site it. I have updated my answer with a few other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to post the form data, I picked *applied to* in *search by Graduate School* in *search by Graduate Application* *program -> MS*, *Term -> Fall* *Major -> Industrial Engineering* and *Year -> 0* :

```
import requests

data = {"bygradschool": "1","status": "0", "add_univ": "0",
        "byappln": "1", "g_prog": "1", "g_major": "8",
        "g_term": "1", "g_year": "0", "gre_total": "0",
        "gre_quant": "0", "gre_verb": "0",
        "agre_range": "0", "sub_search": "Search"}
p = requests.post("http://edulix.com/unisearch/index.php", data)
print(p.content)
```

If you look at the content returned it is exactly as you see in your browser. The form data and the request can also be seen in firebug or chrome:

[image]